# How to validate the form in pylons in the same controller action that initially rendered it?

Tags: python, pylons

I have the following controller:

```
class FormtestController(BaseController):

    def form(self):
        return ender('/simpleform.html')

    @validate(schema=EmailForm(state=c), form='form', post_only=False, on_get=True,
              auto_error_formatter=custom_formatter)
    def submit(self):
        return 'Your email is: %s  and the date selected was %r.' % (
            self.form_result['email'],
            self.form_result['date'],
        )
```

The first action is for initial form rendering and the second one is when the form is submitted. Is it possible to merge them and just use an if request.POST == 'POST' to check if the form has been submitted?

I tried it and move the @validate decorator to the form action but it gives me a WSOD and the server stops serving:

```
class FormtestController(BaseController):

    @validate(schema=EmailForm(state=c), form='form', post_only=False, on_get=True,
              auto_error_formatter=custom_formatter)
    def form(self):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            return 'Your email is: %s  and the date selected was %r.' % (
                self.form_result['email'],
                self.form_result['date'],
            )
        return render('/simpleform.html')
```

Is there a way to have a single action and still use the validate decorator?

Answer (score 1):

Silly me, it was just simple. Here's my code:

```
class FormtestController(BaseController):

@validate(schema=EmailForm(state=c), form='form', post_only=True,
          on_get=False,
          auto_error_formatter=custom_formatter)
def form(self):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        return 'Your email is: %s  and the date selected was %r.' % (
            self.form_result['email'],
            self.form_result['date'],
        )
    return render('/simpleform.html')
```